# Attempting crossing() with 5 fold split df get "Error: `x` must be a vector, not a `rsplit/vfold_split` object"

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a variable train_cv that looks like this:

```
> train_cv
#  5-fold cross-validation using stratification 
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  splits            id    train                   validate               
* <named list>      <chr> <named list>            <named list>           
1 <split [72K/18K]> Fold1 <df[,10] [72,000 × 10]> <df[,10] [18,001 × 10]>
2 <split [72K/18K]> Fold2 <df[,10] [72,001 × 10]> <df[,10] [18,000 × 10]>
3 <split [72K/18K]> Fold3 <df[,10] [72,001 × 10]> <df[,10] [18,000 × 10]>
4 <split [72K/18K]> Fold4 <df[,10] [72,001 × 10]> <df[,10] [18,000 × 10]>
5 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5 <df[,10] [72,001 × 10]> <df[,10] [18,000 × 10]>
> glimpse(train_cv)
Observations: 5
Variables: 4
$ splits   <named list> [<rsplit[72000 x 18001 x 90001 x 10]>, <rsplit[72001 x 18000 x 90001 x 10]>, <rsplit[72001 x 18000 x 90001 x 10]>, <rsplit[72001 x 18000 x 90001 x 10]>, <rsplit[72001 x 18000 x 90001 x 10]>]
$ id       <chr> "Fold1", "Fold2", "Fold3", "Fold4", "Fold5"
$ train    <named list> [<data.frame[72000 x 10]>, <data.frame[72001 x 10]>, <data.frame[72001 x 10]>, <data.frame[72001 x 10]>, <data.frame[72001 x 10]>]
$ validate <named list> [<data.frame[18001 x 10]>, <data.frame[18000 x 10]>, <data.frame[18000 x 10]>, <data.frame[18000 x 10]>, <data.frame[18000 x 10]>]
```

I attempted to use the `crossing()` to cross each fold with some mtry paramaters:

```
> model_ranger <- train_cv %>% 
+   
+   crossing(mtry = c(1,2,4,8))
Error: `x` must be a vector, not a `rsplit/vfold_split` object
```

I copied this from a online course which does this very thing, uses crossing on a dataframe that was split into folds using `rsample::vfold_cv()`. Except I am seeing this error message.

Why am I getting this error and how can I cross each of my 5 cv folds with each of the values in `mtry = c(1,2,4,8)`

Comment: Works with `eg_data <- diamonds %>% rsample::vfold_cv(5) %>% crossing(mtry = c(1,2,3))` just does not work with my actual data and I do not know what the difference is between my own data set and this case where it works.

Comment: This error happens intermittently with my actual data and I don't know why. If I knew how to reproduce I'd probably know how to solve.

Comment: Maybe try to solve your problem using the new api instead https://tidymodels.github.io/tune/articles/grid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```
model_ranger <- train_cv %>% expand_grid(mtry = c(1,2,4,8))
```

Comment: as a side note it was happening to me with the gapminder dataset!